# Xamarin, how can I gain a completed state from a command?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView and am using the SelectedItem to call a command and show a modal view.

However, I have an issue where the user can tap multiple times on the listview row and multiple modal views are shown before the view has loaded. Granted this only happens on slower devices.

This is is caused because the command doesn't have any call back.

I wouldn't normally paste code here, but in this case I thought it was more descriptive to provide a screen shot.

I've looked into the AsyncCommands but these seem to be used more to handle errors.

I'm currently thinking about a subscribe approach which is triggered when the modal is exited, however I think there must be another way I haven't thought of.

[image]

Comment: Can you describe this in more detail please ?

Comment: Sorry. I think i missunderstand what you want. I would check the question again.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are having an issue where your view model command is firing multiple times and you want to change it so that it only executes once whilst doing work. There are a few ways you can achieve this but I would start by looking into Prism, they have excellent tooling for this scenario. [ObservesCanExecute](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/commanding.html#observescanexecute) is a great place to look. I dont know if it will support alternative commands but its a pattern worth looking into if you don't already use!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a `Boolean as IsSelected` & make `IsSelected` true when user clicks an item from list & change your condition in setter as below. When your operations are done reset the flag.

This was, there wont not be any duplication of modals. This is what I understood from your question, if there's something else, please let me know.

```
if( _locationAssetSelected || !IsSelected )
{
    IsSelected = true;
    _locationAssetSelected  = value; 
    ..... //your code
    
    _locationAssetSelected  = null;
    IsSelected = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I've looked at this in more detail, if you refer to my code, the first time value variable has a value, which is fine and runs the command, the second time it is null and doesn't proceed, the third time it has the same value as the start and calls the command again... Hope that makes sence.. I think your answer won't help, the reason being that the command doesn't halt the process or wait. Unfortunetly, the subscribe approach seems the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the logic to the command to make sure it doesn't execute multiple times. This is a snippet on the sample/template Forms app which uses this method as a command. Lock seems unnecessary.

```cs
async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
{
    //lock (selectLock)
    //{
        if (item == null || selectionOn)
            return;

        selectionOn = true;
    //}
    
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Text} selected");

    // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");

    selectionOn = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think await would work, but I don’t seem the best able to do that on the command as it doesn’t have await inside it.

Comment: You can use .ContinueWith(t => selectionOn = false)